# VBA - I want to delete buttons which are on top of cells - Minesweeper game

Tags: vba, excel

as the title says, I want to delete buttons which are on top of cells given the cell location.

Here's what I tried so far to no success.

```
Dim r As Range    'range is already given from another function call
Dim butns As button
With Sheet1.Buttons
    butns.Top = r.Top
    butns.Left = r.Left
    End With
Sheet1.Buttons(butns).Delete
```

my attempt would be getting the cells "top" and "left" value and finding the button associated to that value and then deleting it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Surely your code will just move the buttons?

Comment: Indeed it does.. to the same spot basically. I just want it to select the button which is on top of the given cell location and delete it.

Comment: What kind of button is it? ActiveX Control or a Form Control?

Comment: It is form control buttons

Comment: Its a minesweeper game. Basically when you click a button and the cell under the button is blank, it goes through a recursion to find the surrounding blank cells. What I want in this part would be to delete the button which is on top of the cell it is currently selected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way you can really find which button is on top of a cell is to see if the center of the button is contained within the cell's dimensions.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim s As Shape
Dim i As Long
Dim cx As Double, cy As Double

For i = 1 To Sheet1.Shapes.Count
    Set s = Sheet1.Shapes(i)
    cx = s.Left + s.Width / 2
    cy = s.Top + s.Height / 2
    If cx >= r.Left And cx <= r.Left + r.Width And _
        cy >= r.Top And cy <= r.Top + r.Height _
    Then
        s.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

> It is form control buttons –  user3221162 13 mins ago

Is this what you are trying?

Note when looping through shapes, it is important that you identify the `.Type` and `.FormControlType` to ensure that you are only deleting Form Button control else it will delete any shape which meets the criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Loop through shapes
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        '~~> Check if it is a form control
        If shp.Type = 8 Then
            '~~> Check if it is a button
            If shp.FormControlType = xlButtonControl Then
                '~~> Check the cell. Taking B2 as example
                If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = "$B$2" Then shp.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the cell was under a variable?

Comment: How can a cell be under a variable? Or do you mean cell address is stored in a variable?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care for an explanation? I think you are on to serial downvoting today. Guess I will have to report it to a mod :) Let them handle it

Comment: Yes In another function, I set the cell address into a variable.

Comment: How is the address stored in a cell? With the `$` sign or without the `$` sign?

Comment: In that case change `If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = "$B$2"` to `If Replace(shp.TopLeftCell.Address,"$","") = Varb` Where `Varb` is the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you put some info in the shapes' names (Button_1_1, Button_2_1 etc.) and then split out the coords when needed.
With that you can keep track of what button is put where on creation.

Coordinate conversion is often more tricky than expected. You need to take care of zooming, DPIs and other stuff.

Comment: Problem is, there's over 100 buttons to name for a basic minesweeper game.  So that would be extremely slow

Comment: Surely you create the buttons with a macro? In the macro it should be fairly easy to name the buttons according to placement.